# Spring singleton bean's values are sharing with users

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring webapp which has following beans. When 2 users come in to the system at the same time, then both get the same services, whereas it should show each users's own service. shouldn't mix up.

How to do this in current code? CommonWSServiceClass is singleton scope by default.

1. I can remove the instance field `private List<Services> exSVCList = null;` and make it method local (declare it in retrieveExistingService() method). In this way it resolve the issue somewhat I believe. But see below question.
2. After making the above variable to method local, what will happen if two users come at the same time. Both threads are inside method retrieveExistingService(), but user_1 is at the `return exSVCList;` line. Just about to exit from the method. But user_2 come and executing the same method, line `exSVCList = new ArrayList();`. So in this case, when the user_1 finish the execution of method retrieveExistingService(), he will get an empty arrayList, isn't it ? As the bean is singleton, hence only one bean is there. So the size of the arraylist is empty. Because user_2 updated the same variable.

Is my understanding correct? If this is the case, how to handle this in Spring?

```
    @Component
    @Scope(value = "session")
    public class ServiceClass {

       @Autowired
       private CommonWSServiceClass webservices;

       public services[] getExServices(){             
          List<Services> list =  webservices.retrieveExistingService()
       }
    }

 
    @Service
    public class CommonWSServiceClass {

      private List<Services> exSVCList = null;

      public List<Services> retrieveExistingService() {
        
        exSVCList = new ArrayList();
        exSVCList.add(addSomeObj);

        updateList();
    
        exSVCList.add(addAnotherObj);

        return exSVCList;

     }

     private void updateList() {        
       exSVCList.add(Call a Webservice to get the item list.);    
     }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Singletons have to be stateless, so remove the state (private List exSVCList = null) and define it as method variable. If you need to store the state per connected user, it should go to its session as attribute

Comment: Thank you for the hint. This is what I've mentioned in the question 1. 
In question 2, I've asked a scenario when make variable as method local.

Comment: Method variables are not shared between threads

Answer (score 0):

As said the default type of beans in spring are singletons. So they are shared across all requests and application.

You need either `RequestScope` so that a new service will be created for each request

```
@RequestScope
@Service
public class CommonWSServiceClass {
```

or `SessionScope` so that a new service will be created for each session.

```
@Scope(value = "session")
@Service
public class CommonWSServiceClass {
```

### As to your question

> After making the above variable to method local, what will happen if
> two users come at the same time.

```
@Service
    public class CommonWSServiceClass {

      private List<Services> exSVCList = null;

      public List<Services> retrieveExistingService() {
```

You didn't make the field a local variable. You only initialize that field inside a method. The List remains a class field.

So as multiple threads read and write to that field all common laws about concurrency safety should be applied here. **As it is right now you are not safe between multiple threads.**

**If you convert your class field to a local variable however you will be safe**

```
 @Service
    public class CommonWSServiceClass {

      public List<Services> retrieveExistingService() {
        
        List<Services> exSVCList = new ArrayList();
        exSVCList.add(addSomeObj);

        updateList(exSVCList);
    
        exSVCList.add(addAnotherObj);

        return exSVCList;

     }

     private void updateList(List<Services> exSVCList) {        
       exSVCList.add(Call a Webservice to get the item list.);    
     }
```

Comment: Yes I didn't depict it as method local as I gave the sample to depict the question 1. So assume if I make it method local, then the scenario I've mentioned won't happen? Pls elaborate if my understanding is wrong. If we make variable method local, then there won't be a scenario that 2 threads access the same method same time and sharing the variable?

Comment: as you have it in your question, 2 threads will write to the same reference. Everything that has to do with concurrency can go wrong there.

Comment: and yes 2 methods will share the same variable. So that variable must be synchronized and even then I doubt that this is the result that you want

Comment: So the only solution is to change the singleton bean's scope? is this how Spring application should write?

Comment: It is how and what you want to achieve. And in your case it seems that you can convert the class field to a local method variable. In that case the singleton scope is not bad and you are not in danger

Comment: But If you want to leave it as you have it right now, then yes you need to go to either session or request scope

Comment: even I turn the variable to method local, still two users can share the same method local variable as the scenario 2 I've mentioned in my question. So it won't completely resolve the issue. isn't it? And that's why you've mentioned in the earlier comment to make the variable synchronized.

Comment: each method execution has it's own stack and local variables. So 2 requests invoking the same method at the same time will not share anything

Comment: `each method execution has its own stack and local variables.` is this how java works or this is how Spring singleton bean's methods are running?